# Combining means of multiple dataframes into a single one while showing a name for each one

Tags: r, dataframe

**Please let me know if this question needs further / better explanation**

I am pretty new to R and have been trying to do this for about a week now, so maybe somebody can help.

I have two CSV files (actually more but let's use two for simplicity). After reading them as data frames they have a year and a sales column. I then renamed the sales columns so that I later know which sale column belongs to which CSV file. So they would look like this:

```
zz <- "Year  Sales_bmw
       2013   11
       2014   10
       2015   12
       2016   11"
df_bmw <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)

zz <- " Year  Sales_ford
        2013   10
        2014   15
        2015   9
        2016   13"
df_ford <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)
```

Now I could join them together which would give me a data frame with the columns 'Year', 'Sales_bmw', and 'Sales_ford' and I could calculate the mean for Sales_bmw and Sales_ford.

But here comes the thing where I am stuck.

In the end, I want a data frame that holds the mean of each sale column of the other data frames. So it would have 2 entries that look like this(basically the mean of each sale column in the data frames and a name):

[image: end result]

And I don't know how I could get there from the joined data frame (or the bmw and ford data frames themself):

```
bmw_ford <- sales_bmw_df %>% inner_join (sales_ford_df)
head(bmw_ford)

##      Year  Sales_bmw Sales_ford
##    1 2013     11       10  
##    2 2014     10       15
##    3 2015     12       9
##    4 2016     11       13
```

I hope this was somewhat understandable :/ I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Changed it, that should be what head() would display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the wrong thing at the beginning. You shouldn't rename the `Sales` columns, the thing that they're the same in two data frames is perfect. Instead, add another column `Brand` to contain the brand names and combine them together, then use the `summarise` function in the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df_bmw <- data.frame(Year = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016),
                     Sales = c(11, 10, 12, 11))
df_ford <- data.frame(Year = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016),
                     Sales = c(10, 15, 9, 13))
df_bmw <- df_bmw %>%
  mutate(Brand = "Bmw")

df_ford <- df_ford %>%
  mutate(Brand = "Ford")

df <- bind_rows(df_bmw, df_ford)

df_smr <- df %>%
  group_by(Brand) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Sales)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Update:**
Another way to work since you've already changed the column names and join data frames: (but I don't think this is a good practice)

```
library(dplyr)
df_bmw <- data.frame(Year = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016),
                     Sales_bmw = c(11, 10, 12, 11))
df_ford <- data.frame(Year = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016),
                     Sales_ford = c(10, 15, 9, 13))
df <- df_bmw %>% inner_join (df_ford, by = "Year") # shouldn't leave the 'by' parameter

df_smr <- df %>%
  summarise_all(mean) %>%
  select(-Year)

# transpose the data frame
rownames(df_smr) <- c("Mean")
df_smr <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(df_smr)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try `stack` + `colMeans`

```
setNames(rev(stack(colMeans(df[-1]))),c("Name","Mean"))
```

which gives

```
        Name  Mean
1  Sales_bmw 11.00
2 Sales_ford 11.75
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = 2013:2016, Sales_bmw = c(11L, 10L, 12L, 
11L), Sales_ford = c(10L, 15L, 9L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyr` and `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#create data frames

zz <- "Year  Sales_bmw
       2013   11
       2014   10
       2015   12
       2016   11"
df_bmw <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)

zz <- " Year  Sales_ford
        2013   10
        2014   15
        2015   9
        2016   13"
df_ford <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)

df_bmw_ford_mean <- df_bmw %>% 
  #join the data frames
  inner_join(df_ford) %>% 
  #rename the columns
  rename("Bmw" = "Sales_bmw",
         "Ford" = "Sales_ford") %>% 
  #pivot data from wide form to long form
  pivot_longer(cols = c("Bmw", "Ford"), names_to = "Name") %>%
  #create group defined by variable in order to perform mean operation
  group_by(Name) %>%
  #create new data frame adding one column for the summary statistic specified, in this case the mean.
  summarise(Mean = mean(value))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Name   Mean
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Bmw    11  
#> 2 Ford   11.8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>